# Reverse engineer a predictive model from a time series graph

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, model

I have found some real estate plots in a scientific article. These graphs mainly describe, the believes of the author of the development of the real estate market in the future for certain countries.

I am very interested in the techniques used to model this case. Therefore, I tried to contact the author to find out more about his appreciated work, but he does not answer me. Besides this paper some tables and several plots I have no further clues about the model.

Therefore, my question to you is, do you think it is possible to reverse engineer a model based entirely on graphs and tables? Which techniques could be used? Has anybody tried to do that and succeeded?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: 1) If it is a scientific paper there should be a section describing the methodology that is used to get the results and conclusions of the paper. 2) If the predictions are based on the statistical analysis of historical data you would need to get the data set that is used in the analysis.

Comment: The tag `repoducible-research` may be suitable for this question.

Comment: Expectations may depend on your field and sometimes coyness arises out of work with potential patent, intellectual property or financial benefit for the author(s), but otherwise it's not worth the effort to reproduce something the author does not explain; he has placed himself outside serious science. Apart from that, there is usually no sure way to infer the internals of a model from its predictions. Better to put your energies into developing your own model and publishing it.